# Xamarin UI gets updated in 10 seconds after OnPropertyChanged() triggered

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin

A very weird scenario... Maybe someone can help. Breaking my head over this.

```
private string _myText = "Hello";
public string MyText
{
    get { return _myText; }

    set
    {
        _myText = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        //OnPropertyChanged("IsSearching");
    }
}
```

I binded my MyText to a Label in XAML Xamarin view to debug what is going on when I run this method.

```
private async void Edit_Survey_Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyText = "Text Before Long Method";
    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        s.Start();
        Task.Delay(3000).Wait();
        MyText = "Text after long method" + s.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
    });
}
```

So when the button is clicked the text gets updated, amazing but it only gets updated the second time in like 10-15 seconds when it is supposed to get updated in 3! I have no idea why, I have tried so many options on how to run this but I guess it is something to do with MyText being set on a different thread maybe.

I am doing this test because instead of the delay I will have a data download and after the data download I would like to change some UI elements from the initial state. Right now I am in great doubt on how to do it and hopefully some else has come across a similar situation.

________Update 1 as suggested by SushiHangover

```
    private void Edit_Survey_Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsSearching = "Method Start Edit";

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { IsSearching = "Yeeeeehuuuuuuu!"; });


        });
    }
```

Didn't help;

Comment: You are *synchronously blocking* by using `.Wait()`, use `await Task.Delay(3000);` instead. And then in your `TaskRun` wrap the  `MyText` assignment in a `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`.

Comment: Unfortunatly this doesn't work

Comment: However it makes complete sense, I inserted an update on how I implemented what you mentioned. Still doesn't work though. The lable gets updated in like 20 seconds...

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? Are you doing something else on the UI thread?

Comment: Yeah I tried it just now. Nothing else is happening on the UI thread that I know of.

Comment: Can you add the code for the `OnPropertyChanged()` method?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private async void Edit_Survey_Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyText = "Text Before Long Method";
    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    s.Start();
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    s.Stop();
    MyText = "Text after long method" + s.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the label updates but only in like 20 seconds, I totally agree it makes total sene to make the Delay await so after the work is done we will come back and change MyText  but it just doesn't update the UI immidiatly and I have no idea why exactly.

Comment: I suggest that you try this in a new blank application where there is nothing else going on for sure...

Comment: I tried, same story, however if I try it not in a Xamarin context but in the context of a simple Console application it runs perfect. Value gets updated in the console. In the case with Xamarin value gets updated in 20-25 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I ran this code in both a IOs emulator and Android and it works fine:

```
namespace Yuri1
{
public partial class Yuri1Page : ContentPage
{
    async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            s.Start();
            Task.Delay(3000).Wait();

        });

        MyEntry.Text="Text after long method: " + s.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();

    }


        //MyText.Text = "Text after long method" + s.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();        }

    public Yuri1Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


}


}
```

Comment: I also agree with the example above the rapping it in BeginInvokeOnMainThread should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Very greatfull for everyone who participated in this discussion. So after numerous attemts to figure this out it seems that the most appropriate solution looks like this. It seems to work fine with a litle delay that is required in order to update the UI after the delay task is done. In the example I debuged the threads ID and also tried both types of binding x reference and data binding.

```
  List<string> threads = new List<string>();

    private BindableProperty IsSearchingProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("IsSearching", typeof(string), typeof(MainPage), "Hello");

    public string IsSearching
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(IsSearchingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsSearchingProperty, value); }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        BindingContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
        threads.Add(GetThreadId() + " in constructor");
    }

    private string GetThreadId()
    {
        return Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
    }

    private async void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        threads.Add(GetThreadId() + " in method");

        IsSearching = "Method Start Edit";
        MyRef.Text = "Reference Text Start";
        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();

        await Task.Run( () =>
        {
            threads.Add(GetThreadId() + " in task");
            s.Start();
            Task.Delay(3000).Wait();


            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                IsSearching = "Yeeeeehuuuuuuu!";
                MyRef.Text = "Reference Text End" + s.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(); ;
                threads.Add(GetThreadId() + " in task in device begin invoke");
            });
        });

        threads.Add(GetThreadId() + " after task");
        DisplayAlert("My Threads", DiplayThreadInfo(), "Cancel");
        threads = null;

    }

    private string DiplayThreadInfo()
    {

        string threadsInfo = null;

        foreach (var thread in threads)
        {
            threadsInfo ="/"+ threadsInfo + thread + "/"+ Environment.NewLine;
        }

        return threadsInfo;
    }
}
```

After the thread debug we can see that the UI updates are executed in the UI thread. It seems that this is vital, if this is not done problems start to happen. Overall this semms to do the job. Thank you everyone.

Comment: However what is interesting is that if you try to update IsVisible the same way the problem comes back into play.